# Azure SQL Server Pipeline Restore/Copy Process

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-sql-server

I am looking to see if there would be a starting point in retrieveing backups from azure sql and restoring a specific database from a source server to a target server, but through a pipeline, as I'm not really a dba and this is for experimenting purposes, could someone guide me through what should I be looking into ?

Did anyone do anything remotely close to what I'm trying to achieve ? currently i'm looking into some powershell options, but I'd like to see if there are better ways on trying to achieve this, but still through a yaml pipeline.

Comment: For restoring database from a source server to a target server, you may try with Azure CLI for "Copy a database to a new server" :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/scripts/copy-database-to-new-server-cli?view=azuresql#run-the-script .

Comment: @RoyWang-MSFT I assume this could also be integrated into a pipeline with params right? I'm looking to see if this process can be integrated into a pipeline . read through the docs , I was hoping I missed something and there would be another/different approach to this.